# What does this warning means after reading shapefile

Tags: leaflet, r-sf

I read a shapefile using sf to use with leaflet using the following function:

```
metro <- read_sf(dsn = "D:/SOPARI/SofSTATE/ACS/datafinalmetro")
```

I was able to read it but I also received a warning, could you tell me waht does it means?

Warning message:
In evalq((function (..., call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE,  :
  automatically selected the first layer in a data source containing more than one.

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.9-3/topics/sf , specifically about `sf_column_name`.

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez